# Django.js - Reverse for 'django_js_init' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

Having an error using djangojs after I have installed successfully.

In settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...
   'djangojs',
)
```

In my template.html:

```
{% load js %}
{% django_js %}
```

I have tried removing {% django_js %}, there was no error. But when starting to initialize djangojs, the error occurred.

As additional info urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from apps.members.views import MembersDT
urlpatterns = patterns('apps.members.views',
  url(r'^$', 'main', name='members-main'),
  url(r'^add/$', 'add', name='members-add'),
  url(r'^list/$', MembersDT.as_view(), name='members-list'),
  url(r'^(?P<pid>[0-9]+)/$', 'info', name='members-info'),
  url(r'^(?P<pid>[0-9]+)/edit/$', 'edit', name='members-edit'),
  url(r'^(?P<pid>[0-9]+)/delete/$', 'delete', name='members-delete'),
)
```

Comment: Please show your `urls.py`.

Comment: added my urls.py already. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [installation instructions](http://djangojs.readthedocs.org/en/0.8.1/index.html#installation), you need to add this item to the `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^djangojs/', include('djangojs.urls')),
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that one.